# Bitcoin Core on Windows get wallet address

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, windows

I have recently downloaded and installed the Bitcoin core software for Windows. It is still currently syncing at 10.89%. I am unable to find the wallet address anywhere in the application itself. If you could please point out what I am missing here. Do I have to wait until the sync is complete or can I retrieve my wallet address and begin receiving some transactions.

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to find the wallet address anywhere in the application itself.

Little confusion here, there is no one wallet <==> one address.

Your wallet is handling many keys, hence many addresses. You could see addresses as invoices (it has been proposed to rename them to "invoice addresses" btw).

You can (security-wise) but should not (privacy-wise) reuse such invoice addresses.

> If you could please point out what I am missing here.

Assuming you run bitcoin-qt. In order to receive coins, go to the `Receive` tab and click on `request payment`.

You will be given a fresh new invoice address.

Comment: I hope people don't start using "invoice address" for activities that don't resemble the business process of sending invoices and statements and receiving payments to be reconciled against multiple invoices. Bitcoin terminology is already awful and misleading. Wallets that don't contain money. Ledgers that are Journals, Keys that don't open locks, Addresses that are not locations. Orphans that have living parents.

Comment: I believe proposals to change the name "address" at this point are about 8 years too late to have any chance of being adopted.